# font size of the placed plotlegends

Tags: plotting, legending, fonts

I need to fixed the font size "14" for the [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) "degree".

```
ClearAll[a1, plot1];
a1 = {
   {0.82, -109}, {0.98, -75}, {1.12, -57}, {1.17, -52}, {1.30, -43},
   {1.37, -38}, {1.45, -34}, {1.54, -30}, {1.64, -26}, {1.76, -22.9},
   {1.95, -18.6}, {2.06, -16.6}, {2.24, -13.8}, {2.47, -11.2}
   };
plot1 = ListLinePlot[
  a1
  , PlotStyle -> Blue
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-10, -110}}
  , Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}
  , ImagePadding -> 57
  , ImageSize -> 315
  , LabelStyle -> {14.5, GrayLevel[0]}
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[{"degree"}, {Scaled[.8], Scaled[.7]}]
  , Epilog -> {Inset[Style["(a)", FontSize -> 14.5], Scaled[{.89, .25}]]}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: On a side note, I suggest that the use Indentation makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Placed[{"degree"}, ...]` with `Placed[{Style["degree", 14]}, ...]` to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[
 plot1,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for your help. Is there any other ways to get the same result by putting the code within the listlineplot[], but not separately Show[]as  you suggested. Thanks in advance

Comment: @rabink Just use the same option inside `ListLinePlot`.